# Python multiprocessing taking the brakes off OSX

Tags: python-3.x, macos, multiprocessing

I have a program that randomly selects 13 cards from a full pack and analyses the hands for shape, point count and some other features important to the game of bridge.  The program will select and analyse 10**7 hands in about 5 minutes. Checking the Activity Monitor shows that during execution the CPU (which s a 6 Core processor) is devoting about 9% of its time to the program and ~90% of its time it is idle.  So it looks like a prime candidate for multiprocessing and I created a multiprocessing version using a Queue to pass information from each process back to the main program.  Having navigated the problems of IDLE not working will multiprocessing (I now run it using PyCharm) and that doing a join on a process before it has finished freezes the program, I got it to work.

However, it doesn’t matter how many processes I use 5,10, 25 or 50 the result is always the same.  The CPU devotes about 18% of its time to the program and has ~75% of its time  idle and the execution time is slightly **more than double** at a bit over 10 minutes.

Can anyone explain how I can get the processes to take up more of the CPU time and how I can get the execution time to reflect this?  Below are the relevant sections fo the program:

```
import random
import collections
import datetime
import time

from math import log10
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


NUM_OF_HANDS = 10**6
NUM_OF_PROCESSES = 25


def analyse_hands(numofhands, q):

#code remove as not relevant to the problem

        q.put((distribution, points, notrumps))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    processlist = []
    q = Queue()

    handsperprocess = NUM_OF_HANDS // NUM_OF_PROCESSES
    print(handsperprocess)
    # Set up the processes and get them to do their stuff
    start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(NUM_OF_PROCESSES):
        p = Process(target=analyse_hands, args=((handsperprocess, q)))
        processlist.append(p)
        p.start()

    # Allow q to get a few items
    time.sleep(.05)
    while not q.empty():
        while not q.empty():
            #code remove as not relevant to the problem

        # Allow q to be refreshed so allowing all processes to finish before
        # doing a join.  It seems that doing a join before a process is
        # finished will cause the program to lock
        time.sleep(.05)
        counter['empty'] += 1

    for p in processlist:
        p.join()

    while not q.empty():
        # This is never executed as all the processes have finished and q
        # emptied before the join command above.

        #code remove as not relevant to the problem       

    finish_time = time.time()
```

Comment: If you dont need inter-process syncing, you can directly use multiprocessing.Pool.map as its more straight forward. Havn't read the code in detail (too long), but usually not using all cores might be either because of the Queue (waiting for lock) or because of heavy IO.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool` is definitely the way to go. Don't use more processes than you have cores, otherwise they'll waste resources fighting for CPU time.

Comment: I have 6 cores and whether I use 5 or 50 processes the results are the same.  A doubling of execution time.

Comment: Also I am looking at doing some counts on 10**7 items.  Using Queue I can count them individually and then discard them.  It seems to me that Pool will store them all before I can get at them.

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer to the reason why IDLE will not run a multiprocessor start instruction correctly but I believe the answer to the doubling of the execution times lies in the type of problem I am dealing with.  Perhaps others can comment but it seems to me that the overhead involved with adding and removing items to and from the Queue is quite high so that performance improvements will be best achieved when the amount of data being passed via the Queue is small compared with the amount of processing required to obtain that data.

In my program I am creating and passing 10**7 items of data and I suppose it is the overhead of passing this number of items via the Queue that kills any performance improvement from getting the data via separate Processes.  By using a map it seems all 10^7 items of data will need to be stored in the map before any further processing can be done.  This might improve performance depending on the overhead of using the map and dealing with that amount of data but for the time being I will stick with my original vanilla, single processed code.